# How to include the name of the file at the end of the string

Tags: c#, regex

I use Regex and Linq to search all .txt files in a folder which match the pattern. That part of the code looks like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Search(string file)
        {
            return File
                .ReadLines(file)
                .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern))
                .Where(match => match.Success)
                .Select(match => match.Value)
                .ToArray();
        }
```

Then write the matches in a .txt:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath, "*.txt");
var extracts = files.SelectMany(file => Search(file));
File.WriteAllLines("results.txt", extracts);
```

Is there anyway to write the name of the file where the match comes from? I have the names of the files in a string array.

```
var filenames = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt")
                .Select(filename => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename))
                .Select(filename => Regex.Match(filename, namePattern))
                .Where(match => match.Success)
                .Select(match => match.Value)
                .ToArray();
```

My goal "results.txt" example:

> ```
> Example1 **file1.txt**
> Example2 **file2.txt**
> Example3 **file3.txt**
> ```

The "Examples" are the parts already working, the highlits are what I want to achieve somehow. Any help would be appreciated even if I have to rewrite the whole code. Thanks!

Comment: If you use functional syntax, then you have to pass the filename down through the remaining calls. IMO, query syntax would be easier to read/manage because you can refer back to the filename from within your `select`.

Comment: `var extracts = files.SelectMany(file => Search(file).Select(item => $"{file} **{item} **"));`

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Try this :              string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt")
                 .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x), namePattern))
                 .Select(x => string.Format("\*\*\*{0}\*\*\*", x)).ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the file name directly to the match:

```
var extracts = files.SelectMany(file => Search(file).Select(line => line + " " + file));
File.WriteAllLines("results.txt", extracts);
```

If you need to keep the clean "extracts" without the file, you can create anonymous objects:

```
var extracts = files.SelectMany(file => Search(file).Select(match => new {match, file}));
File.WriteAllLines("results.txt", 
                   extracts.Select(extract => extract.match + " " + extract.file));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it something like this:

```
var matches = Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath, "*.txt")
.Where(currentPath => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentPath), pattern))
.AsParallel() // useful if there are many files
.Select(currentPath => 
    new {FilePath = filePath, MatchingValue = File.ReadLines(currentPath)
        .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern))
        .Where(m => m.Success)
        .FirstOrDefault()?.Value
})
.Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.MatchingValue))
.Select(m => $"{m.MatchingValue} {Path.GetFileName(m.FilePath)}");

File.WriteAllLines(@"results.txt", matches);
```

Comment: For some reason I get a blank .txt. Still trying to figure out why.